# Ax 2012 user control not visible to all users on MS Enterprise Portal

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, enterprise-portal

I have created a Ax 2012 user control to add it on MS Enterprise Portal. So i added the user control by adding the web part on EP retail page.

Now the problem is that user control only visible to that particular user who added it. I want this user control to be visible to all the users.

Who to do?

Comment: Post some of your code to let us know what you have tried please.

Answer (score 1):

it seems you have not modified the page but personalized for the current user.
Did you used 'personalize this page? Or 'modify shared page'?